# multi-column indexing in Core Data (iOS)

Tags: ios, ios5, core-data, indexing, multiple-columns

I remember reading somewhere about multi-column indexing in Core Data (iOS), but I can't find that information anywhere.

Is multi-column indexing possible with iOS5 Core Data?

I can set up multiple indexes on single columns, but can't find an option for multi-column index.

Comment: Do you remember this https://www.artandlogic.com/blog/2013/01/optimizing-core-data-searches-and-sorts/ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found what I was looking for in WWDC 2011 videos, what's new in Core Data (iOS5).

They call this "compound indexes", and they are set by selecting the entity in XCode, you then have an "Indexes" field in the inspector when you can set what looks to be a multi column index: "attribute1,attribute2".

I just tested it, and it does work, so multi column index IS supported since iOS5

Answer (score -4):

CoreData has no affordance for the creation or use of multi-column indices. This means that when you execute the query corresponding to your multi-property predicate, CoreData can only use one index to make the selection. Subsequently it uses the index for one of the property tests, but then SQLite can't use an index to gather matches for the second property, and therefore has to do it all in memory instead of using its on-disk index structure.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111865/is-this-a-bug-i-should-submit-to-apple-or-is-this-expected-behavior)

Comment: I think I found what I was looking for in WWDC 2011 videos, what's new in Core Data (iOS5). They call this "compound indexes", and they are set by selecting the entity in XCode, you then have an "Indexes" field in the inspector when you can set what looks to be a multi column index:  "attribute1,attribute2". I will check that this indeed behaves as expected